# how to use vpn connection on nox in windows?

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost

edit: I found my answer

I already know that if I would have a smartphone with an internet connection, I can share the connection through the `Every Proxy` app. This app allows to have an http proxy, and when you share your internet through usb cable, you can enter the proxy that the app has given, on windows. It's actually more helpful if you want to share your vpn connection.

I want to do the same, but in nox. I turn on my vpn and install Every Proxy on nox. The IP address the app give is `172.16.24.15`. but trying this in windows; has no result.
I also used `Fing` to see my simulator IP address and it is `172.16.25.2` for the simulator router and `172.16.25.15` for the android itself.

Answer (score 0):

in the system settings of nox > device > enable network bridge mode > DHCP, I get the IP address `192.168.1.3`. now when I turn on `Every Proxy`, I set the IP address `192.168.1.3` instead of the previous `172.16.24.15`. so I can use this new IP in windows settings and it works.